# Proper way to work with Yandex ClickHouse sparse tables?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm a bit confused with disabled NULL for common types in CickHouse. What the idea behind NULL values restriction?

In Google BigQuery my workflow was to store as much metrics as possible in the same table despite the fact I can store only one field per row.

But in the ClickHouse case, all values would be set to default.

1. Is this ok in terms storage efficiency?
2. What is the common way to aggregate thru such tables? I mean to aggregate only real values (without those which was set as defaults)
3. Maybe I should use different table scheme structure?

p.s. Data is cryptocurrency metrics such as (price, volumes, community sizes, on chain data).

p.s.s. My common queries are aggregation by time period, i.e.

```
SELECT time_bucket('10 seconds', time) AS period, max(value), avg(value), fisrt(value), last(value) GROUP BY id, period
```

Some math over fields (+,-,/,*), moving average, standard deviation. (but this part is can be done with pandas on the next steps).

[time_bucket](https://docs.timescale.com/v0.9/api#time_bucket) is timescale's primitive for aggregation over the time period.

Answer (score 2):

Clickhouse support NULLs since mid 2017. Currently NULLs support in ClickHouse is mature enough to be used on production environment (tiny issues are still possible). Documentation is not ready yet.

Syntax is like that:

```
create table test (x Nullable(UInt8)) Engine = TinyLog;
```

Generally then some column support NULLs that means it's a bit slower, because NULL state should be stored and processed in some 'special' way. That's true for any database.

ClickHouse is originated from Yandex Metrika, probably originally NULLs were not nessecary for Metrika scenario.